# How to typeset a double subscript (sic!) not a subsubscript correctly

Tags: subscripts

I have a function `f`that I want to restrict to a certain sub-domain of the domain it has been originally defined for. Usually, in mathematics this is illustrated by a vertical bar followed by the restricted set in the lower right of the function symbol. E.g. usually I write

```
f_{\mid A}
```

which means `f` restricted to the set `A`.

Unfortunately, I have a sequence of functions `f_i` that has already a subscript. If I write

```
f_{i_{{\mid A}}}
```

I do net get an LaTeX error, but the result is semantically wrong. `\bar A` is *not* a subscript of `i` which happens to be a subscript of `f`, but `\mid A` is a subscript of `f_i`. Especially, the font size of `{\mid A}` should not be smaller than the size of `i`, but have the same size.

However, if a write

```
{f_i}_{\mid A}
```

(which btw would be semantically correct) I get a "double subscript error".

Alternatively, I could write

```
f_{i \; \mid A}
```

and get the correct font size for `\mid A` but it is placed too high. `\mid A` should be below `i`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{\hat{f}_i}_{\mid A}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As I have already found out, the problem occurs only *with* the accent above `f`. But I need the accent there.

Comment: `f_{\bar{A}}`,  `f_{i_{\bar{A}}}` ... ?

Comment: You say that “`\mid A` should be below `i`.” But should it really? The convention I’ve seen before is that double subscripts are *collapsed* and put on the same subscript level, at the same size, and sometimes separated by a comma/semicolon.

Comment: Although I think no-one will be confused, your post and @Zarko's comment both slip into using `\bar` in place of `\mid`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a known problem, see [Why am I getting a double subscript error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253080/why-am-i-getting-a-double-subscript-error):

```
{\hat{f}_i}_{|A}
```

will issue a “double subscript” error. The cure is adding `{}` to the base.

On the other hand, I can't see so much a difference between this and

```
\hat{f}_{i\,|A}
```

which I'd prefer.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}_{i\,|A}
\qquad
{{}\hat{f}_i}_{|A}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\mid A` is semantically wrong, although leading to the same result.

Comment: Surely the semantically right symbol is not `\mid` or `|` but `\rvert`?

Comment: @LSpice Surely not `\rvert`.

Comment: Why not?  I thought that indeed this was exactly what it was for, a vertical bar on the right.  Surely `|` is semantically neutral and, in particular, has no idea where or why it is in a formula.