# Why does this throw an error for double subscripting?

Tags: subscripts

```
{\mathbf{\hat{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{hom}}}}_{jj}^{1/2}
```

So I thought if you enclosed the term with parentheses, you can do a double subscript, but this throws a double subscript error, and I'm not sure why. My guess is that the hat command is interfering but I don't know why that's the case.

Comment: Please clarify what the intended result is supposed to be. E.g., are `jj` and `1/2` supposed to be subscripts and superscripts to (a) `\mathrm{\mathrm{hom}}` or (b) `\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{\mathrm{hom}}`?

Comment: The latter, I thought enclosing it with parentheses is enough.

Comment: Under normal circumstances you would be right (I mean enclosing with parentheses). But... there is a but: when the content of the math list within `{...}` 
 is a single accent atom (with or without a sub- or superscript), the grouping is removed. That's what causes the error here. See [Why am I getting a double subscript error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253080/82917)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm listing two possible solutions. In the first solution, I employ round parentheses to provide some visual clues for readers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text directive
\usepackage{bm}       % for \bm directive (\bm more robust than \boldsymbol)

\begin{document}
$(\widehat{\bm{\Sigma}}_{\hom})_{jj}^{1/2}$
\quad\text{or}\quad
$\widehat{\bm{\Sigma}}_{\hom}{}_{jj}^{1/2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `bm` is more robust: `\usepackage{amsmath,bm}` and `\bm{\Sigma}` (but `\boldsymbol` becomes an alias for `\bm`).

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for your suggestion; I've incorporated it in the answer

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `\mathbf` for Greek letters, hope the below code may meet your expectation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}}_{{\mathrm{hom}}_{jj}^{1/2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had the answer \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
$\mathbf{\hat{\sum}}_{{\mathrm{hom}_{jj}}^{1/2}}$
\end{document} :-) +1