# Double subscript error on ${\tilde a_0}_0$?

Tags: subscripts, braces, arguments

`${a_0}_0$` compiles fine: ${a_0}_0$

`${\tilde a_0}_0$` yields a "double subscript" error.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Oh, does TeX stackexchange not render math expressions?

Comment: Oh ok this question already exists: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253080/163063

Comment: MathJax is not TeX and, anyway, we're most interested in TeX code, not in the approximate output you might get with MathJax.